# cyrillic letters are not properly displayed in ggplot in RStudio and exported PDF

Tags: r, ggplot2, encoding, character-encoding, visualization

I try to plot sparklines using ggplot2 and facet_grid. By default, facet labels (relatively long) are displayed vertically on the left. I want to display it on the right horizontally. First, I use `switch = "both"`, then `angle = 0`. But facet margins are too large (even if I display it on the right or use `strip.text.y.left = element_text(margin = margin(0,0,0,0))`). Also, I tried to use `facet_wrap(ncol = 1)`, but I've got the same picture. Plus, when I export PDF, the graph doesn't display correctly.

UPD: I found out that the problem is with encoding. When I put latin names in facet labels, it worked correctly.

Here is the code.

```
day <-  rep(1:7, 7)
variable <- paste("Кемеровская область", rep(1:7, each = 7))
value <- rnorm(49, 1.5, 1)
df <- data.frame(day, variable, value)

ggplot(df, aes(x = day, y = value)) + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free_y", switch = "both") +
  geom_area(fill = "lightblue") + 
  geom_line(size=0.3) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c(NA, "black"), guide = F) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0, vjust=0.7, hjust= 1,
                                         margin = margin(0,0,0,0)))
```

Pictures:

[In R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uPhc.jpg)

[Exported PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ricvm.jpg)

UPD: session info:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape_0.8.8 ggplot2_3.3.2 dplyr_1.0.2   readxl_1.3.1
```

Comment: Hm. When I run your code on my machine everything works fine without the large margins in your image. Also, exporting to PDF works fine except that on my machine it does not show any letters but just dots, which probably is a different issue related to my locale settings or some missing font or ....

Comment: Hm... I tried to run the code from another device. For Windows I've got the same output, but for Mac the graph displayed correctly and exported PDF was also with dots. Do you use Mac?

Comment: Yep. I'm on MacOS. Should have added that to my comment.